# Spring boot Version upgrade from 2.1.8 to 3.0.1 deployment failing (But the same application works with 2.7.18)

Tags: spring, version, upgrade

```
   I am working on upgrading one of our Spring boot microservice. Initially the spring boot version was 2.1.8.RELEASE and Java version was 1.8 and Gradle (6.7) is the build tool used while developing the service. 
   Now we are trying to upgrade both spring boot version (3.2.2) and Java version (21). 
 After modifying the build.gradle with required dependencies, the build is success. But while deploying its failing with **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map '********' bean method**.**
```

As I mentioned, the initial version was 2.1.8.RELEASE,
I started upgrading the spring boot version using every release. I mean 2.1.9.RELEASE, 2.1.10.RELEASE,2.1.11.RELEASE and so on. **While I upgraded with Spring boot 2.5.0 the build failed with Gradle version. I have upgraded gradle version from 6.7 to 7.2**. The build and deployment was success.
I continued upgrading spring boot version with every release... Both build and deployment success. While I tried to upgrade with **spring boot (2.6.0)**, **build was success. But deployment failed due to circular dependencies. The error was suggesting to add following property to applications.properties spring.main.allow-circular-reference = true**. I followed the same, both build and deployment was success. I continued upgrading spring boot version with every release till 2.7.18. Until this both build and deployment is success.
Finally, I have upgraded **java version to 17 and spring boot version to 3.0.1**. With this upgrade build is success but the deployment is failing with UnsatisfiedDependencyException. We are using constructor based injection and the Description of the error is Parameter 1 of constructor in *********** required a single bean, but 2 were found.
I have added @Qualifier("****") annotation with all the places whereever this error was mentioned. With this changes, circular reference issue solved. while deploying now I am getting different error. **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map '********' bean method**
We are using openapi.yaml to define the model, request and responses. In our controller we are using @Controller annotation and we are redirectring the @ReqeustMapping("/") to the swagger-ui. We wrote a method named index() with this @ReqeustMapping("/") mapping and this method returns a string "redirect:swagger-ui/index.html?url=/******/v3/api-docs/". This index is where the below exception occurs  **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map '********' bean method**

Comment: Please read [ask]